# how to pass id to controller in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have used link_to to call controller action.

```
       <%= link_to "Inactive", {:controller => :leave_details, :action => :deactivate}, {:method => :post } %>.
```

but my requirement is to pass id also to controller action but when i try to pass id(:id=>leave_detail.id) it is not showing in params. my params look like

```
        {"_method"=>"post", "authenticity_token"=>"3vfyGQ5V6GQXRt2aQt+DOT0b3eGgP7B401uclnIGLUU=", "action"=>"deactivate", "controller"=>"leave_details"}.
```

In route file i have added

```
       resources :leave_details do
         post :deactivate, :on => :collection
       end
```

can anyone tell me what is going wrong in this code or what i am missing.
thnks

Comment: why do you want to pass an `id` in a `collection` route? why don't you use named routes?

Comment: actually, i found this route declaration from a blog. if u have any other route solution, then please provide it to me. thnks